# Making Sections and rows with SortableJS Svelte

Tags: svelte, sortablejs

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ea2a1cc9eeca44b9aabe953364f2aa25?version=3.35.0)

I am trying to create sections and rows with SortableJS in svelte. I want to be able to reorder sections, reorder rows within sections, and drag rows to new sections. I cannot figure out how to set the new order of the nested items in the section.

I have provided a REPL above. Moving the sections works and you can see that the underlying data's order changes. But with the rows I get an error. I don't know how to access the `items` within the section on `sortRow`

Here is my data structure.

```
    let stages =[
    {
        id: 1,
        section: "SECTION",
    items: [
        { id: 1 },
        { id: 2 },
        { id: 3 },
    ]
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        section: "SECTION2",
    items: [
        { id: 4 },
        { id: 5 },
        { id: 6 },
    ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I would use a different library that already integrates with Svelte, e.g. [`svelte-dnd-action`](https://github.com/isaacHagoel/svelte-dnd-action).

Comment: @brunnerh I already tried that library.It doesn't handle nested lists with async data very well. I went down a whole rabbit hole with that library.